# Why does Windows Azure Western Europe have U.S IP Address?

Tags: azure

Like the question says, I'm really having a problem where, although I've signed up for a Western Europe Windows Azure VM, whenever I access a site or service from this server I'm getting assigned a U.S IP Address.

This is really problematic because those services require my IP to be in Europe. Anyone else have this issue and know how I can change the IP somehow?

Comment: I would absolutely open a support ticket, explaining that you need a European IP address.  It should be free; you should get a response the same working day.  IMHO...

Comment: I would have if it was simple, but alas first I have to upgrade to a special developer account before I can even open a support thread even when I'm already paying for the VM. Then when I do try to purchase the developer account, it needs to call my local mobile number to verify I'm "human". Since I don't have a local number right now, I can't even purchase the developer account for getting support.... Can you believe this, from Microsoft..

Comment: Yes, I can believe it :)  Try creating a new "outlook.com" identity for yourself, and try getting a 30-day trial subscription under that account.  You should have carte blanche to open a ticket then.

Comment: The IP ranges for the data centers are listed [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2013/08/14/windows-azure-datacenter-ip-ranges.aspx) - did you compare your assigned ip to these to see if it falls within the correct DC? I'm pretty sure Tech support cannot assign you a specific IP address.

Comment: Did you know that IP addresses do not "have locations"? Your services are requiring that your IP address comes from an ISP located in Europe. They have a list of ISPs in Europe, and of the IP address ranges allocated to those ISPs, and they're saying that your IP address isn't in one of those ranges.  They have neglected the case where an non-European company may have a data center in Europe that uses an IP address range assigned to a non-European company.

Comment: @John Saunders - you're quibbling.  The fact is, if you opened www.google.com in a coffee bar in London, you'll see an entirely different page than if you opened www.google.com in downtown Seattle.  I'm pretty sure Azure tech support *CAN* assign an IP address that fits the OP's requirements.

Comment: @paulsm4: first, there's no need for you to be sure. They either can, or they cannot. Second, I'm trying to make the point that, as designed, the IP protocol does not associate a location with an address. Any such association is based on an assumption which is, occasionally, false. I once worked in the USA at a company based in England, and I had a "UK" IP address. Only, by definition, it was not a "UK" address, as there is no such thing in the definition of the IP protocol.

Comment: @John Saunders: Please stop getting hung up on the "IP Address" - you're taking the problem too literally.  Q: When I fire up a browser in a coffee bar in London, how does it "know" I'm in the U.K. (and not Seattle, WA)?  What heuristics might be used?  Q: How can I do "the same kind of thing(s)" with my Azure VM?  Any links or suggestions would be welcome.  TIA!

Comment: @paulsm4: If google.com gets your location wrong, it's not a tragedy. If your services actually _require_ you to be "in Europe", then it's a bit more of an issue, isn't it? They're both making the same mistake, but one is making it in a context where it's unimportant, the other is making the mistake in a more important context. You wouldn't want an "Internet Emergency Call" system to send the police or ambulance to the wrong address, would you? Then such a system should not rely on IP address for location.

Comment: I'm feeling more and more hopeless with Microsoft these days. Isn't it logical for most commercial/enterprise services to provide a basic level of support after you've purchased their services? Well, Azure REQUIRES you to pay for ANY official support on top of the monthly VM costs. I can't even find a basic contact email in my dashboard without paying for it. I had to post in the MSDN forum and still waiting for a reply...

Comment: @paulsm4 You are referring to something completely different than what the OP was asking.  There are multiple ways that a website tries to identify the location of a user, but typically a website "knows" what region you are in based on your DNS server, not based on where your IP address is registered.

Comment: @user2028856, it's the same for Azure and for AWS.  Support costs money, and the VMs are priced to be as cheap as possible for people who don't need hand holding.

Answer (score 4):

To add on to John's comment above, every Azure IP address is registered to Microsoft in the US.  There is no option for support to provide you with a "European IP address" since such a thing doesn't exist in Azure.  You should work with the other service provider to explore alternative options to requiring IP addresses registered to a European address since their strategy ultimately won't work as more services move to shared cloud infrastructures.

Comment: You've got to be kidding me... And Microsoft wants Azure to compete with the likes of Amazon AWS or any other VPS providers? I would have thought that it's kinda logical to have your IP address in the same location as your VPS...