# What's the exactly azure server location when you choose West Europe

Tags: azure, location

I have choose the west Europe as my cloud server location, but the ip address shows the server is in United States, does somebody know about this?

someone told me there's already a question been answered,[Why does Windows Azure Western Europe have U.S IP Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339187/why-does-windows-azure-western-europe-have-u-s-ip-address)
but my question is a little different, all other cloud service in my subscription is West Europe IP, except some are United States, and how can i ensure that the server is locate in West Europe?

Comment: I know MS have a sizable location in Dublin, Ireland.

Comment: The link is in the banner at the top "This question already has an answer here..."